# Android Camera Video is blank with white lines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, video-capture, android-camera2

I have implemented Camera2 API of Android using `MediaRecorder` to record video from the Camera. The Camera Previews are working fine and the video file is also created successfully without any errors. However, the output video is blank and has white flickering lines.

This is the output video I get.

[image: Video output from MediaRecorder]

The code for preparing `MediaRecorder`

```
val surface = MediaCodec.createPersistentInputSurface()
surface.release()

val outputFile = createFile(applicationContext,"mp4")
val mMediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile.absolutePath)
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10_000_000)
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30)
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(matchedResolution.width, matchedResolution.height)
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
mMediaRecorder.setInputSurface(surface)
```

Creating the session.

```
val previewSurface = surfaceView2.holder.surface

val captureCallbackVideo =
    object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {}
        override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
            // session configured
            val previewRequestBuilder =
                cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(TEMPLATE_RECORD)
                    .apply {
                        addTarget(previewSurface)
                        addTarget(surface)
                        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, Range(30,30))
                    }
            session.setRepeatingRequest(
                previewRequestBuilder.build(),
                null,
                Handler { true }
            )
        }
    }

cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(mutableListOf(previewSurface, surface), captureCallbackVideo, Handler { true })
```

For starting the recording

```
mMediaRecorder.prepare()
mMediaRecorder.start()
```

For stopping

```
mMediaRecorder.stop()
mMediaRecorder.release()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had figured it out. The problem was with the input surface of `MediaRecorder`. Apparently, the way of Google's code of `camera2` at GitHub is not right in setting up the `Surface` for `MediaRecorder` correctly.

The solution is that we should not provide `Surface` as input to the MediaRecorder, but `prepare` the `MediaRecorder` without a `Surface` and then use its internal `Surface` for our `CaptureRequest`

```
mMediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10_000_000)
//Uncomment on physical device, comment on emulator
//mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(matchedResolution.width, matchedResolution.height)
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30)
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile.absolutePath)
try {
    mMediaRecorder.prepare()
} catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    return
}
```

For creating session

```
val previewSurface = surfaceView2.holder.surface

val captureCallbackVideo =
    object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {}
        override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
            // session configured
            val previewRequestBuilder =
                cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(TEMPLATE_RECORD)
                    .apply {
                        addTarget(previewSurface)
                        addTarget(mMediaRecorder.surface)
                        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, Range(30,30))
                    }
            session.setRepeatingRequest(
                previewRequestBuilder.build(),
                null,
                Handler { true }
            )
        }
    }

cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(mutableListOf(previewSurface, mMediaRecorder.surface), captureCallbackVideo, Handler { true })
```

For starting recording:

```
mMediaRecorder.start()
```

For stopping a recording:

```
mMediaRecorder.stop()
mMediaRecorder.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used below code I think might be issue in setVideoEncodingBitRate

```
recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
recorder.setVideoFrameRate(16); //might be auto-determined due to lighting
recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);// MPEG_4_SP
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Comment: This is not the issue. I have already tried different bitrates.